# HTML5 tiny bottom page is clipped off

Tags: javascript, css, html

I'm creating a HTML5/Javascript game, where the layout needs to be always absolute positioned. That means, when I'm gonna resize the window, the content should be scaled, but not overflowed, so no scroll bars, which allows me to scroll through the content.

Therefore I'm using a flexbox, where the outside div container is stretched to the window width and height size (100%). It almost works, but there is still a very small overflow on the bottom.

Here is a demo on JSfiddle [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mathew11/3sshbtzk/) and [DEMO Fullscreen](https://jsfiddle.net/mathew11/3sshbtzk/embedded/result/). The strange thing is, that this kind of clipping only appears if the result is shown on full screen. Then, a vertically scroll bar appears too. It also appears on usual browser like Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

It only happens vertically, horizontally it's okay.

My questions is, how can I avoid that?

CSS:

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#game {
    position: absolute;

    background-color: #940020;
    border-color: #5c51d4;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}


#opRow, #gameRow, #playerRow {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: forestgreen;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 20px;
}  

#myCanvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#opRow {
    height: 15%;
}
#gameRow {
    height: 40%;
}
#playerRow {
    height: 45%;
}

#playerCard1, #playerCard2, #playerCard3, #playerCard4, #playerCard5 {
    max-width: 90%;
    height: 90%;
    margin: 1vh;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: #555555;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#opCard1, #opCard2, #opCard3, #opCard4, #opCard5 {
    height: 90%;
    margin: 1vh;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: #555555;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin: 2vh;
}

#playerCard, #opCard {
    height: 90%;
    margin: 1vh;
    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: #555555;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#adout, #cards {
    height: 90%;
    margin: 1vh;

    border-style: dashed;
    border-color: #555555;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#cards {
    height: 90%;
    margin: 1vh;
}

#gameRow25, #gameRow75 {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}


#gameRow75 {
    width: 75%;
}

#gameRow25 {
    width: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is not with your code, but with JSFiddle. The navigation bar at the top, courtesy of JSFiddle, is breaking the style. I would advise you to use a text editor instead of JSFiddle, as it is only really intended for sharing code snippets, not full-blown editing. If you copy and paste the code into files, the styling works fine (although you have to insert `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css_file.css">` in your HTML file to make it utilise the CSS).